# GIMP - How to use oilify and Emboss effect to make rubber material?

Tags: gimp, effects, texture

I am trying to make a plain looking rubber material, slightly polished as shown in the left image. What I tried is in the right image, using these steps:

1. Used Oil brush to make basic shape.
2. Applied RGB noise.
3. Applied Embroidery/Furr filter.
4. I also tried the emboss effect; it did not work.

How can I make the image look like moulded rubber material?

[image: Left] [image: Right]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to the answer give by Bestorio, in that I've also used the Lighting Effects filter, but with some differences.

Here I applied correlated RGB noise to a 50% grey layer above a red filled layer, with the blending mode of the noise layer set to hard light, then I scaled the noise layer to make the particles bigger, then created a new layer from visible and blurred it slightly, then applied the lighting effects.

Here I show the blurred noise, then the lighting effects applied.

[image]

Here are the settings I used for the Lighting Effects, although one could adjust these as required.

[image]

Finally, you could use an image of a paint splash as a layer mask to reveal the texture.

[image]

Comment: Both answer helped me. This looks more perfect.

Comment: Hi, @Billy , What type of Layer Mask you used in last?

Comment: @LaraFlow - it's just a regular layer mask. I copied and pasted an image of a black paint splash onto the layer mask, then anchored it to the layer mask, and inverted it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the result you're looking for can be achieved with Lighting effects.
Following your steps up to the RGB noise, and then navigating to

Filters > Light and Shadow > Lighting effects

Within that menu turn on the Bump Map, then edit the material settings to your liking.

This quick mockup was made with Bump Mapping set to a Linear curve and Maximum height of 0,01. By editing the material settings you can adjust how shiny the surface will be, and by adjusting the max height of the bump map you can change how defined the surface texture is.
[image: Plastic paint sample]